# How to prevent square from fluctuating in size as it moves away form the origin?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a grid where if the mouse points over a square in the grid it turns red, however, it doesn't seem to be working where the square takes up multiple cells and I cannot seem to figure out why.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let x = canvas.width;
let y = canvas.height;

var xtiles = canvas.width / 32;
var ytiles = canvas.height / 32;

var posX;
var posY;

console.log(x)

function drawTiles() {

  tileStartx = 0;
  tileStarty = 0;
  tileEndx = 32;
  tileEndy = 32;

  for (let i = 0; i < (ytiles + 1); i++) {
    for (let t = 0; t < (xtiles + 1); t++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(tileStartx, tileStarty, tileEndx, tileEndy);
      ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      tileStartx += 32;
      tileEndx += 32;
    }

    tileStartx = 0;
    tileEndx = 32
    tileStarty += 32
    tileEndy += 32
  }

  tileStartx = Math.floor(posX / 32) * 32
  tileEndx = tileStartx + 32
  tileStarty = Math.floor(posY / 32) * 32
  tileEndy = tileStarty + 32

  console.log("x start: ", tileStartx, "x end: ", tileEndx);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(tileStartx, tileStarty, tileEndx, tileEndy);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    posX = event.clientX;
    posY = event.clientY;
  });

  // console.log(posX , posY);

  drawTiles();

}


setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

I tried to create a grid where when the mouse hovered over a part of the grid it would highlight that segment in red in that frame. To accomplish this I tracked the cursor location and then calculated which square it would be in by dividing the number by 32 and rounding it down after I would multiple it by 32 again to get it to fit the square perfectly. However, when pasting the red square it would get larger and cover more than just 1 tile as it moved away from the origin.

At origin:

[image]

Away from origin:

[image]

Comment: Why do you add a new event listener every 100 ms?

Answer (score 1):

#### The rect is expecting the last two paramaters to be *size* not *end* values 8-)

Your first call to `.rect` is correct; your second is wrong.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect

[image]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let x = canvas.width;
let y = canvas.height;

var xtiles = canvas.width / 32;
var ytiles = canvas.height / 32;

var posX;
var posY;

console.log(x)

function drawTiles() {

  tileStartx = 0;
  tileStarty = 0;
  tileEndx = 32;
  tileEndy = 32;

  for (let i = 0; i < (ytiles + 1); i++) {
    for (let t = 0; t < (xtiles + 1); t++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(tileStartx, tileStarty, tileEndx, tileEndy);
      ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      tileStartx += 32;
      tileEndx += 32;
    }

    tileStartx = 0;
    tileEndx = 32
    tileStarty += 32
    tileEndy += 32
  }

  tileStartx = Math.floor(posX / 32) * 32
  tileEndx = tileStartx + 32
  tileStarty = Math.floor(posY / 32) * 32
  tileEndy = tileStarty + 32

  console.log("x start: ", tileStartx, "x end: ", tileEndx);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(tileStartx, tileStarty, 32, 32); // <------- CHANGED
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
    posX = event.clientX;
    posY = event.clientY;
  });

  // console.log(posX , posY);

  drawTiles();

}


setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

#### Performance

See also the excellent point raised by @vr in the comments below.

Comment: You should really move that event listener outside of `draw` so it isn't added every tenth of a second.